# Isolating/manipulating data in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo

Using pandas dataframe I was able to access stock data from yahoo finance. I managed to organize it on a monthly basis as I am attempting to see how a stock performs in a given month over a multi year period. Specifically, how many times a given month has a positive price increase within the period (If the price always is up in the month of December, I would want to see the % and the # of occurrences). I'm currently using one stock 'MSFT' to test but ideally it would analyze many more. My problem: I can't seem to access the data in the dataframe for this purpose.

Here is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessMonthBegin

input_file = ['MSFT'] 
money_list = []

for ticker in input_file:

    data = web.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", datetime(2014,1,1), datetime(2015,12,31))

    monthly_data = data.index.to_period('M')
    min_day_in_month_index = pd.to_datetime(data.set_index(monthly_data, append=True).reset_index(level=0).groupby(level=0)['Open'].min())
    custom_month_starts = CustomBusinessMonthBegin(calendar = min_day_in_month_index)

    site_dict = {'Open':'first','High':'max','Low':'min','Close': 'last','Volume': 'sum','Adj Close': 'last'}
    mthly_results = data.resample(custom_month_starts, how=site_dict)

    month = { 0:'JAN', 1:'FEB', 2:'MAR', 3:'APR', 4:'MAY',5:'JUN', 6:'JUL', 7:'AUG', 8:'SEP', 9:'OCT',10:'NOV', 11:'DEC' }

    print mthly_results
```

Comment: do you get an error? if so what is the error?

Comment: @ Tadhg McDonald-Jensen No error, just can't figure it out.

Comment: the way I understand your question is _"I got the data from the web correctly, I manipulated the data into the form I wanted, then I couldn't do anything with it"_ which doesn't make all that much sense. What are you specifically trying to do?

Comment: I can't seem to isolate all months of January in the dataframe (or any other months).

Comment: I want to take each month type (Jan, Feb, etc) and see how each one performed in the 2 year timeframe.

Comment: learn  pandas groupby. method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question can be simplified greatly. (Your code is overly complex).

First you find the minimum for each month. 
Then you join back into the original data set.
You now have the day on which the minimum occurred as well as the other columns.

The second part of your question is more tricky. To find the percent increase and decrease you need a little more machinery.

I added a class to keep track of the increases and decreases for a given month.
Then I iterate over all the minimums and find the percent change from month to month.
Then print it in a nice dataFrame.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas.io.data as web
import pandas as pd

class MonthlyChange(object):
    months = { 0:'JAN', 1:'FEB', 2:'MAR', 3:'APR', 4:'MAY',5:'JUN', 6:'JUL', 7:'AUG', 8:'SEP', 9:'OCT',10:'NOV', 11:'DEC' }

    def __init__(self,month):
        self.month = MonthlyChange.months[month-1]
        self.sum_of_pos_changes=0
        self.sum_of_neg_changes=0
        self.total_neg=0
        self.total_pos=0
    def add_change(self,change):
        if change < 0:
            self.sum_of_neg_changes+=change
            self.total_neg+=1
        elif change > 0:
            self.sum_of_pos_changes+=change
            self.total_pos+=1
    def get_data(self):
        if self.total_pos == 0:
            return (self.month,0.0,0,self.sum_of_neg_changes/self.total_neg,self.total_neg)
        elif self.total_neg == 0:
            return (self.month,self.sum_of_pos_changes/self.total_pos,self.total_pos,0.0,0)
        else:
            return (self.month,self.sum_of_pos_changes/self.total_pos,self.total_pos,self.sum_of_neg_changes/self.total_neg,self.total_neg)


for ticker in ['MSFT'] :

    data = web.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", datetime(2014,1,1), datetime(2015,12,31))
    data['ymd'] = data.index
    year_month = data.index.to_period('M')
    data['year_month'] = year_month
    first_day_of_months = data.groupby(["year_month"])["ymd"].min()
    first_day_of_months = first_day_of_months.to_frame().reset_index(level=0)
    last_day_of_months = data.groupby(["year_month"])["ymd"].max()
    last_day_of_months = last_day_of_months.to_frame().reset_index(level=0)
    fday_open = data.merge(first_day_of_months,on=['ymd'])
    fday_open = fday_open[['year_month_x','Open']]
    lday_open = data.merge(last_day_of_months,on=['ymd'])
    lday_open = lday_open[['year_month_x','Open']]

    fday_lday = fday_open.merge(lday_open,on=['year_month_x'])
    monthly_changes = {i:MonthlyChange(i) for i in range(1,13)}
    for index,ym, openf,openl in fday_lday.itertuples():
        month = ym.strftime('%m')
        month = int(month)
        diff = (openf-openl)/openf
        monthly_changes[month].add_change(diff)
    changes_df = pd.DataFrame([monthly_changes[i].get_data() for i in monthly_changes],columns=["Month","Avg Inc.","#Inc","Avg.Dec","#Dec"])
    print(changes_df)
```

**Explanation:**

The code first grabs the data from the web.

```
data = web.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", datetime(2014,1,1), datetime(2015,12,31))
```

The data looks like this.

*Date, Open, High,  Low,  Close, Volume, Adj Close*

*2014-10-29, 46.43,46.70,46.34,46.61,3027610,44.77*

Then it gets the year and month for every row in the table.

```
year_month = data.index.to_period('M')
```

Then it adds a new column in the table that has the year and month only.

```
data["year_month"] = year_month
```

The data now looks like this

*Date,   Open, year_month,   ... (rest of columns)*

*2015-03-11,  42.31,    2015-03 ...*

Next we group on the column year_month. Then we find the minimum value in the column Open for each month.
We need to do a groupby because need to collect all the days in the month into a group so that we can take the min.

```
monthly_mins = data.groupby(["year_month"])["Open"].min()
```

Now we have all the monthly minimums in a single table. We know the day on which the minimum occurred. 
But we don't know what all the other columns are. 
So we join this back into the main table and we get only the monthly minimums.

```
month_min_open_df = data.merge(monthly_mins,on=["year_month","Open"])
```

Comment: It works nicely. Now I'm trying to get it to run through all stocks in the market (this part I can do) and identify which stocks have a particular month that has gone up or down consistently (ex:100% of the months of june ) in the last 5 years and print out the stock ticker, the month, and the average gain into a csv file. I'm fairly new to coding so I'm a little lost in your code. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Do you want me to explain the code step by step?

Comment: If you're willing to spend the time, that would be great! Much appreciated!

Comment: Can I get a + answer out of it?Ok, its on my to do list.

Comment: I realized the month of January is always 1 month shorter than the others in terms of occurrences, why is that? Thanks

Comment: What month you do compare the first month in the list to?

Comment: I thought you were comparing the price at the beginning of the month to the price at the end of the month ???

Comment: I could do that. but currently it compares the low for january vrs the low for feburary

Comment: If you could do that, it would be extremely appreciated. Thanks again for the explanation, it helped alot!!

Comment: Hi, I'm still working on it...any chance you can guide me in the right direction? Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I fixed this before. Here you go.

Comment: dude, its awesome! THANKS. I'm trying to get it to scan through a list of stocks (that part is no problem), but what I can't figure out is how to print out only the stocks that for example have a #Inc or #Dec that's equal to 100% of the occurrences (Basically always up, or always down in a certain month). Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello again, the program is finished and works great (thanks again for the help). The only thing that doesn't seem to be working right is the dates, for some reason the returns in the Avg Inc. and Avg Dec columns do not match the monthly returns I see when looking on yahoo. I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929068/python-pandas-dataframe-data-not-matching-source/37929636#37929636

Any help is appreciated! Thanks