# Python - Pandas Dataframe - data not matching source

Tags: python, pandas, logic, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to use monthly stock data from yahoo to analyze patterns. For some reason, the monthly returns the program is spitting out in a dataframe for a particular stock (ATVI) do not match the returns from the actual yahoo site. I compared monthly returns for the 2015 period and included columns for average increases and decreases as well as the # of occurrences of each.

Yahoo link: https://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=ATVI&a=00&b=1&c=2015&d=11&e=31&f=2015&g=m

My code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader._utils import RemoteDataError
import csv
import sys
import os
import time

class MonthlyChange(object):
    months = { 0:'JAN', 1:'FEB', 2:'MAR', 3:'APR', 4:'MAY',5:'JUN', 6:'JUL', 7:'AUG', 8:'SEP', 9:'OCT',10:'NOV', 11:'DEC' }

def __init__(self,month):
    self.month = MonthlyChange.months[month-1]
    self.sum_of_pos_changes=0
    self.sum_of_neg_changes=0
    self.total_neg=0
    self.total_pos=0
def add_change(self,change):
    if change < 0:
        self.sum_of_neg_changes+=change
        self.total_neg+=1
    elif change > 0:
        self.sum_of_pos_changes+=change
        self.total_pos+=1
def get_data(self):
    if self.total_pos == 0:
        return (self.month,0.0,0,self.sum_of_neg_changes/self.total_neg,self.total_neg)
    elif self.total_neg == 0:
        return (self.month,self.sum_of_pos_changes/self.total_pos,self.total_pos,0.0,0)
    else:
        return (self.month,self.sum_of_pos_changes/self.total_pos,self.total_pos,self.sum_of_neg_changes/self.total_neg,self.total_neg)


for ticker in ['ATVI']: 

try:

    data = web.DataReader(ticker.strip('\n'), "yahoo", datetime(2015,01,1), datetime(2015,12,31))
    data['ymd'] = data.index
    year_month = data.index.to_period('M')
    data['year_month'] = year_month
    first_day_of_months = data.groupby(["year_month"])["ymd"].min()
    first_day_of_months = first_day_of_months.to_frame().reset_index(level=0)
    last_day_of_months = data.groupby(["year_month"])["ymd"].max()
    last_day_of_months = last_day_of_months.to_frame().reset_index(level=0)
    fday_open = data.merge(first_day_of_months,on=['ymd'])
    fday_open = fday_open[['year_month_x','Open']]
    lday_open = data.merge(last_day_of_months,on=['ymd'])
    lday_open = lday_open[['year_month_x','Open']]

    fday_lday = fday_open.merge(lday_open,on=['year_month_x'])
    monthly_changes = {i:MonthlyChange(i) for i in range(1,13)}
    for index,ym, openf,openl in fday_lday.itertuples():
        month = ym.strftime('%m')
        month = int(month)
        diff = (openf-openl)/openf
        monthly_changes[month].add_change(diff)

    changes_df = pd.DataFrame([monthly_changes[i].get_data() for i in monthly_changes],columns=["Month","Avg Inc.","Inc","Avg.Dec","Dec"])


    print ticker
    print changes_df
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the average daily up/down price moves, you could:

```
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader

data = DataReader('ATVI', "yahoo", datetime(2015, 1, 1), datetime(2015, 12, 31))[['Open', 'Close']]
open = data.Close.resample('M').first() # get the open of the first day, assign date of last day of month
close = data.Close.resample('M').last()  # get the close of the last day, assign date of last day of month
returns = close.subtract(open).div(open) # calculate returns
```

to get:

```
Date
2014-01-31   -0.052020
2014-02-28    0.134232
2014-03-31    0.047131
2014-04-30   -0.032866
2014-05-31    0.040561
2014-06-30    0.081474
2014-07-31   -0.007539
2014-08-31    0.049020
2014-09-30   -0.124263
2014-10-31   -0.031083
2014-11-30    0.066503
2014-12-31   -0.042755
2015-01-31    0.038251
2015-02-28    0.103644
2015-03-31   -0.022366
2015-04-30    0.017387
2015-05-31    0.095879
2015-06-30   -0.046850
2015-07-31    0.042863
2015-08-31    0.121865
2015-09-30    0.108758
2015-10-31    0.124919
2015-11-30    0.089384
2015-12-31    0.003630
Freq: M, Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

To get the mean by months, you can:

```
returns.groupby(returns.index.month).mean()
```

to get:

```
1    -0.006884
2     0.118938
3     0.012383
4    -0.007739
5     0.068220
6     0.017312
7     0.017662
8     0.085442
9    -0.007752
10    0.046918
11    0.077943
12   -0.019563
```

Comment: I'm looking for the average increase/average decrease columns in the dataframe to match the returns I would get from using the monthly data from the website posted above. Return = (open-close)/open

Comment: See update with average difference in `Open`/`Close`.

Comment: @ Stefan, thanks for the help. To be honest, I have no idea where to put your code into mine. Would it be possible for you to modify the code I posted? Also, I'm looking to get the return based on the Open of the 1st day of the month and the Close of the last day of the month (sorry if that wasn't clear before) 

return = (Close of last day-Open of first day)/Open of first day

Then take the average for every same month --> If the period is 2 years then (July 2014 + July 2015)/2 = Avg Return